# pandas.DataFrame.loc returning empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone shed some light on why I can't locate a row from the .loc operation based on my search criteria which is in date format?

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

stockCode = 'AAPL'
data = yf.download(stockCode, '2014-10-20', '2015-01-27')


#dfClose = pd.DataFrame(data.Close.values)
dfOpen = pd.DataFrame(data.Open.values)


dflist = dfOpen.values    
dfClose = pd.DataFrame({"open": data.Open.values,
                            "year": data.Close.index.year.values,
                         "month":  data.Close.index.month.values,
                        "day":  data.Close.index.day.values,
                            "date": data.Close.index.date})
```

```
dfClose[0:5]

open    year    month   day date
0   98.320000   2014    10  20  2014-10-20
1   103.019997  2014    10  21  2014-10-21
2   102.839996  2014    10  22  2014-10-22
3   104.080002  2014    10  23  2014-10-23
4   105.180000  2014    10  24  2014-10-24

RETURNING EMPTY FRAME
dfClose.loc[dfClose['date'] == "2014-10-21"]
open    year    month   day date

Also trying a date range but no luck
dfClose.loc['2014-10-21':'2014-10-24']
open    year    month   day date
```

This seems to work when I use a variable later on. Is this because it's in a np array?

```
floating_Max = np.amax(dflist)
print ("Max\n", dfClose.loc[dfClose['open'] == floating_Max])
```

```
Max
           open  year  month  day        date
28  119.269997  2014     11   28  2014-11-28
```

Comment: What type is `dfClose.date`? My guess is that it's not `str`.

Comment: So the dfClsoe is pandas data frame, and it looks like the date portion is a np array. 

print (type(dfClose))

print (type(data.Close.index.date))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Try `dfClose.dtypes`. My guess is that it's a `datetime64`. If so, that's what the type you need to compare it to when checking for equality.

Comment: The date type is an object. All the others are int64 other than open which is float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `date` column is an `object` type in dfClose. Try the following to convert it to datetime64 -

```
dfClose['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfClose['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

The `dfClose.loc[dfClose['date'] == "2014-10-21"]` should work now.

If you want to apply `.loc` by a date-range, the `date` column might have to be set as an index after converting to type datetime64. To do that, try the following -

```
dfClose = dfClose.set_index('date')
```

The command `dfClose.loc['2014-10-21':'2014-10-24']` should work then.

Comment: Yes, it was set to an object. Converting in and indexing as you suggested worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @erips thought. Here is what I do for filtering if the type is pandas datetime (my guess of what type it is).

```py
date_to_check = pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 20)
filter_mask = df['Date'] > date_to_check
df_filtered=df[filter_mask]
```

If for whatever reason it is not already a datetime object you can cast it as such:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc` indexes on the index name, therefore when you write `dfClose.loc[dfClose['date'] == "2014-10-21"]` you are passing a Series of bools to `loc`. This is the mistake.
What you could do is `dfClose[dfClose['date'] == "2014-10-21"]` to get the rows where date matches that string (watch out for the type of the values, comparing a `str` to a `datetime` won't return what you expect)

Comment: @erip `df.iloc` indexes on the row number, while `df.loc` on the index name. see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

and after checking the docs, I have to say my answer is not correct, since `loc` also accept a boolean array :) so the mistake in the question is probably on the date type vs str comparison

Comment: The date is set as an object at the moment according to dtypes. Do I need to convert it to a string first?

Comment: just use `datetime`:
```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime(year, month, day)
```
and use d for the comparison. This allows also > or < comparison, etc.

Otherwise, yes just convert it to `str`